# Why this function is returning nil?

Tags: clojure

I'm studying Clojure and Functional Programming, in order to practice, I am working on the 4clojure problems.

this function, (not the best approach..  I know) is working. 
(Reverse interleave) However, the function is retuning nil.

```
(defn reverse_interleave
  [coll ss]
  (let [xx (dec ss)]
    (loop [coll (reverse coll) s xx _ss ss ret `()]
      (if (nil? (first coll)) (do (println :ret ret) ret))
      (when-let [x (first coll)]
                        (recur 
                          (rest coll)
                          (if (zero? s) xx (dec s))
                          (if (or (= 1 _ss) (zero? _ss)) 0 (dec _ss))
                          (if (zero? _ss)
                            (map-indexed #(if (= % s) (cons x %2) %2) ret)
                            (cons (list x) ret))
                            ))
      )) ret)


(reverse_interleave (range 9) 3)
```

The question is... Why?

Comment: You have a variable `ret` defined in the loop but it won't exist outside the loop. The last `ret` in the function is outside the loop so it's not the same variable. You even get a CompilerException about it when you evaluate your code.

Comment: klebervirgilio, can you refine your question title a little -- just the headline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to remember here that Clojure doesn't really do *statements* like most imperative languages. With `do` it is possible to evaluate multiple expressions for side effects and then return the value of the last one, and several constructs like `let` and `fn` contain an implicit `do`. But it's not possible for any expression other than the last one to halt evaluation and say "we're done" unless it's throwing an exception. As such, the whole line

```
(if (nil? (first coll)) (do (println :ret ret) ret))
```

can only be seen by its side effect. It will evaluate either as the value in `ret` or as `nil`, and then it will be discarded.

Then we open a `when-let`. Because it's a variant of `when`, this will either return the value of its body if the conditions are met, or `nil` if not. The body is an instruction to `recur` to the beginning of the loop, so this loop can only terminate in the value `nil`.
The natural fix seems to be to take the last paren of the `if` form and move it after the `when-let` so that that entire form is the value of the else-case. Your code as it is also fails to compile for me because it uses the name `ret` outside the loop which creates it, but with that gone it seems to work as intended:

```
(defn reverse_interleave
  [coll ss]
  (let [xx (dec ss)]
    (loop [coll (reverse coll) s xx _ss ss ret `()]
      (if (nil? (first coll)) 
        (do (println :ret ret) ret)
        (when-let [x (first coll)]
          (recur 
           (rest coll)
           (if (zero? s) xx (dec s))
           (if (or (= 1 _ss) (zero? _ss)) 0 (dec _ss))
           (if (zero? _ss)
             (map-indexed #(if (= % s) (cons x %2) %2) ret)
             (cons (list x) ret))))))))

(reverse_interleave (range 9) 3)
;;returns ((0 3 6) (1 4 7) (2 5 8))
```